# Error loading Joomla Frontend - localhost redirect error (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

Tags: redirect, localhost

I am new at using Joomla and trying to learn the program for a class I m currently taking.  I apologize for asking this question again but I am still not clear based on the answer given to previous questions.

I was initially using Joomla 3.7 and upgraded today to 3.7.5, also started creating categories, menus and articles.  When I tried viewing the frontend I got the localhost redirect too many times error.  Up to last evening the frontend worked fine it just started this error today.  I am also using XAMPP as the server.

I attempted to make sense of the  htaccess file and see if I could enter the code to stop the redirect, but I was not 100% clear as to where that goes.  Can someone please assist me.  I will really like to get the hang of this software.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling your `.htaccess` file and see if that helps. If that doesn't help, then you are likely using an SEF plugin that is causing this mess. If disabling (renaming) your `.htaccess` file fixes the problem, then this might be caused by 1) a hardcoded redirect to https when your Joomla website is already doing that or 2) a wrong redirect rule.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happened to me and I solved it by disabling the "language filter" plugin.

I hope it could help someone. :)

Cheers!!